# Derivative of additive and multiplication functions

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I'm watching a machine learning lecture from MIT https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nFTQ7kHQWtc&t=1063s where following is given :

[image]

Given $x+y$ why is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 1 $ & $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 1 $ ?

Is this logic correct :

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = x^{1-1} = 1 $

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = y^{1-1} = 1 $

Given $xy$ why is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = y $ & $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = x $ and/or how is computed ?

Do I need to use product rule (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) ?

Comment: When taking a partial derivative on one variable, treat your function as a function of only *that* variable, i.e. treat all the other variables as *constants*. Eg. for $f(x,y)=xy$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=y$ just because for $f(x)=Cx$ you have $\frac{df}{dx}=C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partial derivative in $x$-direction acts only on changes regarding $x$, the variables in other directions are treated as constants:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y,z) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h, y, z) - f(x, y, z)}{h}
$$
which leads to 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x+y) = 
\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x}x \right)+
\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x}y \right) = 1 + 0 = 1 
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(xy) = 
y \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} x \right) = 
y \cdot 1 = y
$$

Comment: when setting to constant the variable is set to the constant 0 ?

Comment: No, the value is not important. In the case $x+y$ we know that the derivative of a constant vanishes, so $\partial_x y = 0$. For $xy$ we know we can pull out a constant (linearity of the derivative), so $\partial_x (xy) = y \partial_x x$.

Answer (score 1):

Partial derivatives are calculated exactly as ordinary derivatives setting constant the other variables and using the same rules, thus

for $f(x,y)=x+y$

- $f_x=1+0=1$
- $f_y=0+1=1$

for $f(x,y)=xy$

- $f_x=1\cdot y=y$
- $f_y=x\cdot 1=x$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x,y)=x+y$ and $g(x,y)=xy$.

For $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, treat $y=C_1$ as a constant. So $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}(x+C_1)=1$$ 
For $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}$, treat $x=C_2$ as a constant. So $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}(C_2+y)=1$$ 
For $\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial x}$, treat $y=C_3$ as a constant. So $$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}(C_3x)=C_3=y$$ 
For $\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial y}$, treat $x=C_4$ as a constant. So $$\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}(C_4x)=C_4=x$$

Answer (score 1):

In order to find partial derivatives such as $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} $ you assume the other variable is constant and differentiate your function with respect to $x.$

You may have to use product rule or other rules if the function is complicated.

For example in case of $f(x,y)= 5x^2 y + 3 y^2 x $  we have   $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 10xy+ 3y^2 $ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 5x^2+6yx. $